# Kafka Streams issue in scala - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, sbt, apache-kafka-streams

build.sbt file used is as below :

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
val kafka_streams_version = "2.0.0"   
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(   
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-streams" % kafka_streams_version % Provided,  
  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % kafka_streams_version % Provided
)
```

below 2 lines in Scala  are giving the below exception

```
val builder : StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder
val text: KStream[String, String] = builder.stream[String, String]("streams-input")'''
```

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder**    at
>   TradesApp$.main(TradesApp.scala:21)   at
>   TradesApp.main(TradesApp.scala)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>     ... 7 more

Comment: Hi @mamatha, you're telling SBT that Kafka-Streams is provided. How can you check your environment will add the related dependencies at runtime ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `% Provided`, or you must ensure kafka clients and streams jars of version 2.0.0 for Scala 2.12 are in the classpath of the process where your code runs

Answer (score 2):

If you are running through IntelliJ you can edit the Run configurations and enable the configuration `Include dependencies with "Provided" scope`. Of course, you must assure that those dependencies are provided in runtime